# User-defined distance functions in FindClusters

Tags: cluster-analysis

I am trying to use `FindClusters` to segment data points into two special parts

[data](http://pan.baidu.com/s/1dD13ZX3)

```
ListPlot[data, PlotRange -> All, AspectRatio -> Automatic]
```

It is clear that these points can be divided into two parts, each radial arm can be treated as one part.  I've tried different `DistanceFunction`s but can not get what I want, and I don't know how to define a right distance functions.

```
Show[
  ListPlot[FindClusters[data, 2, DistanceFunction -> CosineDistance][[1]],  
    AspectRatio -> Automatic, PlotStyle -> Blue],
  ListPlot[FindClusters[data, 2, DistanceFunction -> CosineDistance][[2]], 
    AspectRatio -> Automatic, PlotStyle -> Red], 
  PlotRange -> All]
```

[image]

Is there any way to solve this problem?

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I hope you will become a regular contributor.  To get started,  1) take the introductory [tour] now, 2) when you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge, 3) remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t), and 4) give help too, by answering questions in your areas of expertise.

Comment: A figure is missing, or the reference to it needs to be deleted.

Comment: A simpler code to plot the clusters of the data is to use: ( cls = FindClusters[data, 2, DistanceFunction -> CosineDistance]; ListPlot[cls] )

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Here is one solution.

1. Find a small number of nearest neighbors (NN's) for each point.
2. Make a graph each node of which corresponds to a data point and each edge corresponds to a NN's pair.
3. Partition the graph into connected components, or communities, or cliques.

In order the last step to work well, it might be a good idea to remove the points in the center of the data of the question.

**The question says the desired partition is for "two special parts," but I see four "special" parts in the plot. That is why my solution explanations show four parts. The solution also works if two parts are desired.**

Here are the *Mathematica* commands.

1. Finding the NN's

   ```
   nf = Nearest[data];

   pointToIndexRules = Dispatch[Thread[data -> Range[Length[data]]]];

   numberOfNNs = 20;
   dataNNs = Map[{#, Complement[nf[#, numberOfNNs], #]} &, data];
   ```
2. Making the graph edges (pairs of connected nodes)

   ```
   graphPairs = 
   Flatten@Map[
    Function[{p}, # <-> p & /@ Complement[nf[p, numberOfNNs], p]], 
    data] /. pointToIndexRules;
   ```
3. Optionally remove points at the center

   ```
   indsToRemove = Select[data, #.# < 0.01 &] /. pointToIndexRules;

   graphPairs=Select[graphPairs,!(MemberQ[indsToRemove,#[[1]]] ||             MemberQ[indsToRemove,#[[2]]])&];
   ```
4. Make the graph object

   ```
   dataGraph = Graph[graphPairs];
   ```
5. Find partition of the graph and the data

   ```
   clsInds = FindGraphPartition[dataGraph, 4];

   cls = Map[data[[#]] &, clsInds];
   ```
6. Plot the clusters

   ```
   ListPlot[cls, AspectRatio -> Automatic]
   ```

Here is the result of step 6.

[image]

If the center points are removed (which I think is a more robust method) then it is better in step 5 to use

```
clsInds = KCoreComponents[dataGraph, 3]
```

Here is the result using that option:

[image]

If we want to see the data as being made of two parts then in step 5 we can use

```
clsInds = FindGraphPartition[dataGraph, 2];
```

and what we get is this result:

[image]