# Conditional Clustering of a set of 3D points

Tags: machine-learning, cluster-analysis

I have a set of 3D points and I would like to know how to cluster them such that every point in a given cluster is at most a certain distance (let's assume `EuclideanDistance` for the purpose of this question) from at least one point in that cluster. For example, suppose there are $5$ points `{1, 2, 3, 4, 5}`, If point $1$ is at most `0.35` units from point $2$, then they belong in the same cluster and if point $3$ is at most `0.35` units from point $2$ or point $1$ then it also belongs to that cluster. If on the other hand, point $4$ is more than `0.35` units from either points $1$, $2$, or $3$, then it doesn't belong in that cluster and so on.

I've scanned through most of the clustering questions but none as specific as this. If there is, I will gladly delete this one.

I've tried using `ClusteringComponents`, `FindClusters` and `Nearest`, but it's not clear how to combine their options to make it work.

Here is a sample of the [3D point set](http://pastebin.com/zcYqgcUU) . Assume `0.35` distance separation as the distance criterion. The output should just be a list of lists of 3D points, with each sub-list containing all points in a given cluster. In the data provided each line is the `{x, y, z}` coordinate of a given point.

Comment: One way is to use bisection clustering and use the desired max in-cluster distance in the stopping criteria. What is the expected size of your datasets?

Comment: @AntonAntonov, about 200 to 300 points.

Comment: For that data size a better approach might be (1) to make a graph with nodes corresponding to the points and edges between nodes / points within the max distance, and (2) find graph components / clusters.

Comment: @AntonAntonov can you post an answer with that approach?

Comment: Just did that -- I hope it is close to what you want.

Comment: As described, it is possible the result could be dependent on order of examining the points (this might or might not be desirable).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For moderate data sizes one approach is:

1. to make a graph with nodes corresponding to the points and edges between nodes / points within the max distance, and
2. find graph components / clusters.

The obtained clusters would adhere to the condition by the graph construction. Code for implementing this approach follows.

Get the data linked in the question:

```
data = Import["http://pastebin.com/raw/zcYqgcUU", "Table", 
  "FieldSeparators" -> " "]
```

Calculate the distances between the points in a matrix:

```
distMat = 
  DistanceMatrix[data, DistanceFunction -> EuclideanDistance];
Do[distMat[[i, i]] = \[Infinity], {i, Length[distMat]}];
```

Optional examination of distances:

```
Histogram[Flatten[distMat]]
```

[image]

Pick a maximum distance and set elements exceeding it to infinity:

```
distMat = distMat /. {(x_ /; x > 2.5) :> \[Infinity]};
```

Make a graph from the obtained weighted adjacency matrix:

```
gr = WeightedAdjacencyGraph[distMat]
```

[image]

Find clusters / communities in the obtained graph:

```
CommunityGraphPlot[gr]
```

[image]

Visualize the found clusters in 3D:

```
ListPointPlot3D[data[[#]] & /@ FindGraphCommunities[gr], 
 PlotStyle -> PointSize[0.02], BoxRatios -> Automatic]
```

[image]

Note, that better or tighter clusters can be obtained using different max distances, and one can investigate for what max distances the graph becomes disconnected.

Comment: Thanks a lot. This is indeed what I seek.

Comment: @RunnyKine Great -- here are related/similar [question](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/95014/34008) and [solution](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/95029/34008).

Comment: Nice, +1 for that one too.

Comment: This works really well and it's also easy to get the number of clusters and the data within each cluster.

Answer (score 1):

Take for example the following data

```
data1 = {RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[3, 0.5], 100], 
RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[5, 0.8], 100]} // Transpose;
data2 = {RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[4, 0.4], 100], 
RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[8, 1], 100]} // Transpose;
data = Join[data1, data2] //RandomSample;
```

which will look something like this

[image: data]

**I define the following helper functions:**

---

to find the nearest existing neighbors in existing clusters;

```
nearstPointinGroup[groups_][point_]:=(Nearest[#, point, 1]& /@ groups) //Map@Flatten
```

to calculate the respective distance to the found nearest neighbor in each cluster and filter points that are farther away than the specified radius

```
toDistances[point_, radius_][nearestPoints_]:=
(EuclideanDistance[#, point]& /@ nearestPoints) //DeleteCases[#, _?(# > radius &), 2]&
```

---

The actual clustering algorithm is implemented with a `Module` for capturing the clusters

```
Module[{groups, neighbors, distances, classifier},
groups = <||>;
neighbors[point_] := nearstPointinGroup[groups][point];
distances[point_, radius_] := 
toDistances[point, radius]@neighbors[point];
classifier[point_, radius_] := 
distances[point, radius] //Sort //Keys //First[#, Length@groups + 1] &;
(*note the new second argument to First that gets applied if the list is empty *)

appendToGroups[point_, radius_] := 
If[KeyExistsQ[groups, classifier[point, radius]], (*if Cluster already exists*)
AppendTo[groups[classifier[point, radius]], point], (*add point to cluster*)
AssociateTo[groups, classifier[point, radius] -> {point}]]; (*else put point in new cluster*)

resetGroups := groups = <||>;
getClusters := groups//Values
]
```

The algorithm can be applied to the data and plotted via

```
resetGroups; (*reset the algorithm*)
Scan[appendToGroups[#, 1] &, data]; (*feed the data to the algorithm*)
getClusters // ListPlot
```

[image: clusters]

Note that there are several points which are quite close together in the graphic but were sorted into different clusters. This is due to the (random) order in which the points are shown to the algorithm. This could be desirable if the order in which the data points are generated has some intrinsic meaning. The following animation illustrates how the algorithm works:

[image: animation]

Showing the points in (random) order to the algorithm does produce varying results both in the way the points are clustered and the number of clusters. One way to make this actually useful might be to provide the algorithm with a initial seed of clusters as in the animation below. The seed used there consists of the four corner points of a unit rectangle. Note how a fifth cluster is formed by the algorithm when no other point within a given distance is found at the respective stage of the run.

[image: animation]